# Rails - Duplicate record with update action

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am having a problem about update action on a basic CRUD controller. This action creates a new record everytime I have called it. I have checked everything a few times and still couldn't figure it out.

post_controller.rb

```
before_action :find_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def edit
end    

def update
    if @post.update(post_params)
        redirect_to @post
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

private

def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:id, :title, :body, :postdate)
end
```

post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

validates :title, presence: true, length: { minimum: 5 }
validates :body, presence: true
validates :postdate, presence: true


def to_param
    "#{id} #{title}".parameterize
end

end
```

Terminal Output just for the requests;

```
Started GET "/yazilar/new" for ::1 at 2014-12-30 20:03:53 +0200
Processing by PostsController#new as HTML
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (23.9ms)
  Rendered posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (31.6ms)
Completed 200 OK in 257ms (Views: 245.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)

Started POST "/yazilar" for ::1 at 2014-12-30 20:04:05 +0200
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"0A3pufznhApS6xDGrfHiVUdhgWO63kD0XGMQ+J/LxJHHsY6N7JtITc0udUjrdYFmvEa49rFzNzmsJ1sbXfM6FQ==", "post"=>{"title"=>"Post_title", "body"=>"<p>Post_body</p>", "postdate(1i)"=>"2014", "postdate(2i)"=>"12", "postdate(3i)"=>"30"}, "commit"=>"Save Post"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (18.4ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("title", "body", "postdate", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "Post_title"], ["body", "<p>Post_body</p>"], ["postdate", "2014-12-30 00:00:00.000000"], ["created_at", "2014-12-30 18:04:05.769804"], ["updated_at", "2014-12-30 18:04:05.769804"]]
  (1.1ms)  COMMIT
  Redirected to http://localhost:3000/yazilar/23-post_title
  Completed 302 Found in 29ms (ActiveRecord: 20.0ms)


 Started GET "/yazilar/23-post_title" for ::1 at 2014-12-30 20:04:05 +0200
 Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"23-post_title"}
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 23]]
  Rendered posts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (1.2ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 191ms (Views: 186.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

Started GET "/yazilar/23-post_title/edit" for ::1 at 2014-12-30 20:04:15 +0200
Processing by PostsController#edit as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"23-post_title"}
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 23]]
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered posts/_form.html.erb (5.1ms)
  Rendered posts/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (8.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 190ms (Views: 186.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)


Started POST "/yazilar" for ::1 at 2014-12-30 20:04:23 +0200
Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qy4qSDrdpqJa1SD4oGgXrGRqFway3PajR8PNQpOJEWO8kk18KqFq5cUQRXbm7HSfn00uk7lxgW63h4ahUbHv5w==", "post"=>{"title"=>"Post_title *update", "body"=>"<p>Post_body</p>", "postdate(1i)"=>"2014", "postdate(2i)"=>"12", "postdate(3i)"=>"30"}, "commit"=>"Save Post"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("title", "body", "postdate", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["title", "Post_title *update"], ["body", "<p>Post_body</p>"], ["postdate", "2014-12-30 00:00:00.000000"], ["created_at", "2014-12-30 18:04:23.969118"], ["updated_at", "2014-12-30 18:04:23.969118"]]
  (6.0ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/yazilar/24-post_title-update
Completed 302 Found in 13ms (ActiveRecord: 6.7ms)


Started GET "/yazilar/24-post_title-update" for ::1 at 2014-12-30 20:04:23 +0200
Processing by PostsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"24-post_title-update"}
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 24]]
  Rendered posts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 186ms (Views: 183.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

This is the _form partial

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |post| %>

<% if @post.errors.any? %>
    <h2><%= pluralize(@post.errors.count, "error") %> prevented this post from saving</h2>
    <ul>
        <% @post.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
            <li><%= msg %></li>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
<% end %>

<%= post.label :title %><br>
<%= post.text_field :title %><br>
<br>
<%= post.label :body %><br>
<%= post.text_area :body, :class => "redactor", :rows => 40, :cols => 40 %><br>
<br>
<%= post.label :postdate %><br>
<%= post.date_select :postdate %><br>
<br>
<%= post.submit %>
```

Comment: what does your form look like  since the update should be posting to  `/yazilar/23 `

Comment: According to your logs, you are getting a request to create a post. not update. how does your form look like?

Comment: Post your view as well if you want more help. I'd guess the start of your form is wrong. It should refer to the object, and if the object has an ID rails will point the submit button to the correct URL. E.g., something like form_for @post ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `form_for` is always pointing to `create` route, you can check your routes running `rake routes` in you app root.

Instead, replace first line in `_form` partial:

```
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |post| %>
```

to:

```
<%= form_for @post do |post| %>
```

Now, the Rails will recognize if @post is a new record, or persisted record and write HTML form with the appropriate action (create or update respectively)

Comment: Alright, check to accept this answer and close this issue